# Using phantom types to represent amounts and exchange rates of currencies

Tags: haskell

[I posted the following snippet to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985896/), and someone said there was much to be improved.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

class (Show a) => Currency a where unphantom :: a

data USD = USD deriving Show
data EUR = EUR deriving Show

instance Currency USD where unphantom = USD
instance Currency EUR where unphantom = EUR

data Amount a where
  Amount :: Currency a => Float -> Amount a
instance Show (Amount a) where 
  show (Amount x) = show x ++ show (unphantom :: a)

data Rate a b where
  Rate :: (Currency a, Currency b) => Float -> Rate a b
-- ...
```

Having to define an `unphantom` function for each currency is a bit annoying but I don't really see a way around it. Also, note that my use of Float to represent monetary values is just a placeholder.

How can I improve this code?

Answer (score 4):

You could rely on the fact the types describing your currencies are `Enum`erable and you can therefore always generate the appropriate token based on the type of an expression. You would write something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module Currency where

data USD = USD deriving (Show, Enum)
data EUR = EUR deriving (Show, Enum)

currencyRep :: Enum a => a
currencyRep = toEnum 0

newtype Amount a = Amount { value :: Float }

instance (Enum a, Show a) => Show (Amount a) where
  show v = show (value v) ++ " " ++ show (currencyRep :: a)

newtype Rate a b = Rate { rate :: Float }

convert :: Rate a b -> Amount a -> Amount b
convert k v = Amount (rate k * value v)

-- example:
main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ show (Amount 3 :: Amount EUR)
```

Now you can really talk about phantom types: `Amount` does not carry around a representation of the currency being used and both `Amount` and `Rate` are `newtype`s meaning that [they will be optimized away](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/Data_types#Newtypes).

Question: Is there a typeclass of singletons out there? It'd be cleaner than using `Enum` (though relying on `deriving` is pretty useful) if we had something like this:

```
class Singleton a where
  unique :: a
```

Comment: It's not standard, but [the package 'Default'](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-default) does what you want. It's not deriveable so I think you're better off with `Enum`...